# Python worker failed to connect back in Pyspark or spark Version 2.3.1

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

After installing anaconda3 and installing spark(2.3.2) I'm trying to run the sample pyspark code.

This is just a sample program I'm running through Jupyter,
im getting an error like

Python worker failed to connect back.

As per below question in stack overflow:

[Python worker failed to connect back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53252181/python-worker-failed-to-connect-back)

i can see a solution like this
I got the same error. I solved it installing the previous version of Spark (2.3 instead of 2.4). Now it works perfectly, maybe it is an issue of the latest version of pyspark.

But I'm using spark version 2.3.1  and python version is 3.7

still, I'm facing that issue. Please help me to solve this error

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("mySparkApp").getOrCreate()
testData=spark.sparkContext.parallelize([3,8,2,5])
testData.count()
```

The traceback is:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 6, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this issue on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: sorry im not getting...what u mean

Comment: I executed the code you provided on my Windows 10 machine and I am running Apache Spark 2.3.0. I am unable to replicate this error.

Answer (score 13):

just add environment variable **PYSPARK_PYTHON** as **python**. It solves the issue. No need to upgrade or Downgrade Spark version. It worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me !. I think it will be different when we use virtual env.

Answer (score 5):

Set your environment variables as follows:

- `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter`
- `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook`
- `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python`

The heart of the problem is the connection between pyspark and python, solved by changing them.

Comment: This worked for me as well. However, I did not have any issues when reading a parquet file and only while creating a dataframe manually.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have properly set the environment variable set,

[image]