# SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back when execute spark action

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

When I try to execute this command line at pyspark

```
arquivo = sc.textFile("dataset_analise_sentimento.csv")
```

I got the following error message:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.: 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure:
Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver):
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
```

I have tried the following steps:

- Check environment variables.
- Check Apache Spark installation on Windows 10 steps.
- Use different versions of Apache Spark (tried 2.4.3 / 2.4.2 / 2.3.4).
- Disable firewall windows and antivirus that I have installed.
- Tried to initialize the SparkContext manually with `sc = spark.sparkContext` (found this possible solution at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53252181/python-worker-failed-to-connect-back) here in Stackoverflow, didn´t work for me).
- Tried to change the value of `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` from `jupyter` to `ipython`, as said in this [link](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-windows-pyspark-4498a5d8d66c), no success.

None of the steps above worked for me and I can´t find a solution.

Actually I´m using the following versions:

Python 3.7.3, Java JDK 11.0.6, Windows 10, Apache Spark 2.3.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just configure the following variables environment and now it's working normally:

- `HADOOP_HOME = C:\Hadoop`
- `JAVA_HOME = C:\Java\jdk-11.0.6`
- `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON = jupyter`
- `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS = notebook`
- `PYSPARK_PYTHON = python`

Actually I´m using the following versions:

Python 3.7.3, Java JDK 11.0.6, Windows 10, Apache Spark 2.4.3 and using Jupyter Notebook with pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. Got it resolved by Java classpath to JDK 11.

[image]