# Configuration of pyspark: Py4JJavaError

Tags: python, pyspark

I am new to PySpark and I encounter a configuration problem in using it.

I tried to create a dataframe using the below code snippet:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession object
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CreateDataFrame").getOrCreate()

# Use the SparkSession object to create a DataFrame
df_day_of_week = spark.createDataFrame([(0, "Sunday"), (1, "Monday"), (2, "Tuesday"), (3, "Wednesday"), (4, "Thursday"), (5, "Friday"), (6, "Saturday")], ["day_of_week_num", "day_of_week"])

# Show the DataFrame
df_day_of_week.show()
```

Below is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 10
      7 df_day_of_week = spark.createDataFrame([(0, "Sunday"), (1, "Monday"), (2, "Tuesday"), (3, "Wednesday"), (4, "Thursday"), (5, "Friday"), (6, "Saturday")], ["day_of_week_num", "day_of_week"])
      9 # Show the DataFrame
---> 10 df_day_of_week.show()

File c:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\data_streaming\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:899, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    893     raise PySparkTypeError(
    894         error_class="NOT_BOOL",
    895         message_parameters={"arg_name": "vertical", "arg_type": type(vertical).__name__},
    896     )
    898 if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 899     print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    900 else:
    901     try:

File c:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\data_streaming\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File c:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\data_streaming\lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:169, in capture_sql_exception..deco(*a, **kw)
    167 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    168     try:
--> 169         return f(*a, **kw)
    170     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    171         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File c:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\data_streaming\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o65.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 16) (host.docker.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedAccept(NioSocketImpl.java:708)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.accept(NioSocketImpl.java:752)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:675)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.platformImplAccept(ServerSocket.java:641)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:617)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:574)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:532)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:179)
    ... 30 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2785)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:971)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2263)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2284)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:530)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:483)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:4177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:3161)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:4167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:526)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:4165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:4165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:3161)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:323)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedAccept(NioSocketImpl.java:708)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.accept(NioSocketImpl.java:752)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:675)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.platformImplAccept(ServerSocket.java:641)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:617)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:574)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:532)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:179)
    ... 30 more
```

Below are my configurations:

- Java 8.0.3710.11
- JDK 17.0.7
- Spark 3.4.1
- Hadoop 3.0.0
- pyspark 3.4.1

However, I can run read.csv succesfully, for example:

```py
test= spark.read.csv('test.csv', header=True, sep='|')
```

Therefore, I cannot figure out the underlying problem.

Please let me know if extra information is required, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it works for your solution,

findspark adds pyspark to your sys.path at runtime

```
pip install findspark
```

Restart the kernel

```
import findspark 

findspark.init()
findspark.find()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a SparkSession object
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CreateDataFrame").getOrCreate()

# Use the SparkSession object to create a DataFrame
df_day_of_week = spark.createDataFrame([(0, "Sunday"), (1, "Monday"),
                                        (2, "Tuesday"), (3, "Wednesday"),
                                        (4, "Thursday"), (5, "Friday"),
                                        (6, "Saturday")],
                                       ["day_of_week_num", "day_of_week"])
# Show the DataFrame
df_day_of_week.show()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works! Does that mean that my environment variable is set wrongly?
I have set SPARK_HOME as C:\Spark\spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3 and Path as C:\Spark\spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3\bin

Comment: No, in my case without findspark its uses the pip install pyspark version of it.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be surprising that both `createDataFrame()` and `read.csv()` don't give an error. The reason is that they are *transformations*, hence Spark is just saving them "for later" but not actually doing anything in accordance with the [*lazy evaluation*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations) paradigm.

You can see this for instance by changing the csv file after `createDataFrame()`.

`show()` on the contrary is an *action* and this is where the Spark engine gets activated.

The relevant error message in your log is:
"Python worker failed to connect back". This hints at some malconfiguration in your Spark architecture.

You will find some possible solutions in:
[Python worker failed to connect back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53252181/python-worker-failed-to-connect-back)

Comment: Thanks for the information on PySpark architecture! Actually, I can execute show() after read.csv(), but executing show() after createDataFrame() prompts the above error, which does not make much sense to me